# I am trying to install ruby-2.2.3 through rbenv build on mac os catalina but getting the following error

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, macos-catalina, rbenv

```
installing bundle gems:
/Users/oyo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)
/private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/.ext/common/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 1 column 9 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/.ext/common/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/.ext/common/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/.ext/common/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:333:in `load_file'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems.rb:297:in `new'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems.rb:297:in `configuration'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:51:in `fetcher'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:76:in `initialize'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:42:in `new'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb:42:in `fetcher'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/resolver/installer_set.rb:37:in `initialize'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:430:in `new'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:430:in `resolve_dependencies'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:373:in `install'
    from /private/var/folders/sk/qhgy79hd7pg63m0_kq67wyb40000gq/T/ruby-build.20200929175743.1274.5WLeHn/ruby-2.2.3/lib/rubygems.rb:558:in `install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:722:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `call'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rubygems can be configured using a `gemrc` file. There, you can set various options  affecting how Rubygems fetches and installs gems by default. This `gemrc` file is supposed to be in YAML format.

In your case, it appears that your current gemrc file is not valid YAML and can thus not be correctly parsed. To fix this, you should check the files at the following locations and fix them to be valid YAML:

- system wide - `/etc/gemrc`
- per user - `~/.gemrc`
- per environment - gemrc files listed in the `GEMRC` environment variable